# Firestore app doesn't call back

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'me building an iOS app with Firestore integrations. I have two Firestore applications set up – one for beta-testing `beta`, and second for production `prod`. They are set up identically (I assume so).

When my app is connected to `beta`, the callback function stop being called. For example when I update a document:

```
self.firestore.collection(collection).document(id).setData(data, completion:{ (error) in
    print("callback") // Never called
}
```

The app is online and according to the Firestore documentation, the callback should be called with no exception.

But when the same app is connected to `prod`, callbacks in the upper example get called well.

Here are my two plists with the credentials to access the Firestore applications (`beta` on the left and `prod` on the right):

[image]

Are there hidden settings for callback calling in the Firestore config or is it because of my app logic?

Comment: I'm not sure: Do you need the blaze plan for multiple firestores as you also need for the realtime database?

Comment: @chronikum There is no such thing a "multiple Firestores" in a single project. There can be only one, and it scales massively.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the reason why callbacks stop being called is not in the Firestore settings but in draining up the day quote of document updates.

Don't get trapped like me :)